# How to Convert string data from ajax success to javascript data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, tinymce

Hello Everybody i have this code and i'm a beginner at ajax things ,and i'm using tinymce jquery and i'm using mention plugin which i found in,so what i'm doing in this code is to make a list of users that i can mention to so i need to make this code run:

mention plugin website is:
https://github.com/CogniStreamer/tinyMCE-mention

> WebMethod Part:

```
 [WebMethod]
    public static string GetUsers()
    {
        return "[{name:'Messi'},{name:'Jason'},{name:'Omar'},{name:'Eren'}]";
    }
```

> and here is the ajax code part:

```
 function dat() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Default.aspx/GetUsers",
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                 alert(data.d);//show me this alert "[{name:'Messi'},{name:'Jason'},{name:'Omar'},{name:'Eren'}]"
                    return data.d;
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    return "";

                }
            });
        }
```

> and here is the jquery tinymce options part:

```
 tinymce.init({



        selector: '#Selector',
        theme: 'modern',
        elements: "rte",
        plugins: [
          'advlist autolink mention lists link image charmap  preview hr anchor pagebreak',
          'searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen',
          'insertdatetime media nonbreaking  table contextmenu directionality',
          'emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker  imagetools'
        ],
        mentions: {
            source:dat()//the default option was [{ name: 'Messi'},{name:'Jason'},......]
        },})
```

so really what i need to do is to convert dat() return part to be just like the default
and i'm really thankful for helping me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question.

What i needed is the `eval()` function. I replaced `source:dat()` with `source: eval(dat())` and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

So your success function is a callback function it's not fired before your dat function completes. So the dat function doesn't return anything.  Try this add asyc: false so the method waits.

```
 function dat() {
     var retdat;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/GetUsers",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json;        charset=utf-8"
            async:false
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
             alert(data.d);//show me this alert "[{name:'Messi'},{name:'Jason'},{name:'Omar'},{name:'Eren'}]"
                retdat = data.d;
            },
            error: function (data) {
                return "";

            }
        });
       return retdat;
    }
```

You should not need this but to answer the title of your question you would use [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

You could also move the tiny mce init function to execute in the success function and you could then keep the call async.

Comment: no it doesn't work what i really need to do is to convert string   `"[{ name: "name1" }, { name: "name2" }] "` to object just like `var x=[{ name: "name1" }, { name: "name2" }];`

Comment: I added to my answer use JSON.parse(mystring)

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
 function dat() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/GetUsers",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
             alert(data.d);//show me this alert "[{name:'Messi'},{name:'Jason'},{name:'Omar'},{name:'Eren'}]"
             var result = JSON.parse(data.d);
              //or you can do without do statically like split(data.d,'"'); then whatever result you get can return that is also
                return result;
            },
            error: function (data) {
                return "";

            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The data itself is already in the correct format.

Since the data is fetched asynchronously you have to call the `process` method in your callback to pass the data back to the plugin. This is explained in more detail [here](https://github.com/CogniStreamer/tinyMCE-mention#function).